# Open popup, click link, open in parent window, close popup?

Tags: javascript, popup

I need help please. What I want to do from my page is to open a popup for which I use this:

```
<a class="txt-button" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://mypage.com/1/index.html','','width=700,height=500,resizable=false,left=0,top=0');return false;">Buy Now</a>
```

When a link on the popup is clicked I want it to open in the main window and for the popup to close.

I've tried many things and cant get it to work:-(

Comment: Note: Be sure to use a relative URL to your popup location.  Otherwise, if the domains domain match (for example, `mypage.com` and `www.mypage.com`) you won't be able to access the parent window.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.opener)

```
window.opener.location.href=x
```

Answer (score 6):

To access main `opener` window **from a pop-up** use the `window.opener` object. You can access any opener property, or even a function call like that *(as long as domains match, as @N Rohler pointed out in the comment to your question)*, for example to navigate use `window.opener.location.href`. Then you close your pop-up with `window.close();` like this:

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="openInParent('http://example.com/');">
  click me
</a>

<script>
  function openInParent(url) {
    window.opener.location.href = url;
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've got that far, but its creating a new tab, and not closing the popup(child)

Comment: I'm learning as I go, but it seems to be working now Thank you!

Comment: I'm using chrome, opening on the same domain (`window.open('/')`), but I still get a cross-origin error.