# Replace Page Links on Popup Page With Javascript to Open in Main (Parent) Window

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a popup player for my radio station website. The window has links to various other pages in my site, some of which are created dynamically by Wordpress widgets.

I want the links to open in the parent window as most of the content isn't suitable for the small popup window.

The approach I have taken is to use javascript to re-write the links as target="parent". This works (from the footer) with the following script.

```
<script>
  var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) {
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('target="_self"','target="_parent"');

}  

      var imgEls = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      for (var i = 0, imgEl; imgEl = imgEls[i]; i++) {
        imgEl.src = imgEl.src.replace('target="_self"','target="_parent"');

}
</script>
```

However, this only works for static links on the page, and not those generated via my slider widget or another widget.

Is there some place this needs to be included, or an adjustment able to be made to find and replace all links after that have been generated?

Edit: To avoid confusion, I'll reiterate the requirement (my attempt was just that, an attempt). I need to re-write all the links, on load, of my popup page, to open in the main site (parent window).

Edit2: While I seem to be able to substitute target="_parent" it's not having the desired effect. Perhaps I need to somehow use [window.opener](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-open-a-link-on-a-parent-window.444624/). Any ideas?

Edit3: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618972/open-popup-click-link-open-in-parent-window-close-popup) works correctly. I think my find/replace is going to have to rebuild this function around the links somehow.

Comment: I can't imagine this working with any link, `href !== target`, or you have really weird `href` values...

Comment: Can you please elaborate? My test worked swapping the values from www.mysite.com to www.mysite2.com. Are you saying even if it does work I won't get the links opening in the parent window?

Comment: This line: `aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('target="_self"','target="_parent"');` doesn't make sense...

Comment: Can you please elaborate? The same line...
`aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('www.test.com','www.test2.com');` works just fine.

Comment: Umh... An url is expected to find from `src` and `href`, `href` doesn't contain text `target =...`, unless it's in a search string? Do you mean: `aEl.target = aEl.target.replace(/_self/, "_parent");`?

Answer (score 0):

You cant replace attribute target, from attribute href. use  el.target and just set the value

```
var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) {
aEl.target="_parent";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$('img').each(function() { 
   var OldSrc = $(this).attr("src");
   var newSrc = OldSrc.replace('target="_self"','target="_parent"');
   $(this).attr("src",newSrc);
});
```

This is short solve.

Comment: I don't understand that solution. It appears just to remove `target="self"`

Comment: just this is a sample. You can convert this to:

var newSrc = OldSrc.replace('target="self"','target="_self"');

@edit: Sorry I wrote "rename". That should be "replace".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm struggling to know what you have added. Do you understand my requirement above? I need to find all the links on my popup page and set them so that they open in the parent.

Comment: As I Understand you want to open a popup and replace all link to _parent ? Like this ?

Comment: If you see my edits above, _parent doesn't work. Strangely _blank does open in the parent window. But in a new tab (obviously). Unfortunately _parent opens in the popup window. I need to use something like a function. See the first solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618972/open-popup-click-link-open-in-parent-window-close-popup)